# On Scheduling Meetings

Tags: meetings, workplace-rhythm, scheduling

One of the few things I've noticed in the workplace is that things often times don't start and end on time. I know that this isn't out of malice, estimated times and actual times to discuss a subject are often not reliable estimates.

Given the logistical implications of arranging to meet:

- Travel Time to and from location
- Initial pleasantries, small talk, etc.
- Set Up

And that most events are scheduled around 30 minute increments, at 1300-1330, 1600-1700.

What would be the possible implications of scheduling in-between?

i.e. 1315-1345, 1645-1745 etc.

Would that 15 minute void have more implications than I think?

---

Update below.

Comment: That's the question, other than a numerical reassignment of time, there shouldn't be any complications right?

Comment: I don't think so either, unless there is data to demonstrate the effects of such a structure, I will presume that it shouldn't have any greater implications in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: What are you actually asking?

Comment: @Lilienthal Would scheduling events/meetings at 15 min intervals have issues beyond timing.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I've implemented it as we are speaking, nothing out of the ordinary. A meet for 1315-1345. Basically 15 minutes after lunch for 30 minutes. If we run over and the other person has something scheduled at 1400, then at least there is 15 minutes of wiggle room.

Comment: You can't solve people being late and meetings dragging on by changing the times. They are either cultural problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meetings are scheduled when you want them, human nature just makes it common for people to make it on the hour or half hour. I've been to meetings that have started at 10 past the hour (E.g. 14:10), just because that worked best for the timings of everyone else.

In the end, you shcedule meetings to fit around yourself, setup time, and everyone that you need to attend the meeting. If you see someone has a meeting until 13:00 and you wanted to host a meeting straight after, you may take into consideration and move your meeting to 13:10, so the previous meeting has time to overrun, they have time to get a coffee, ETC.

Don't forget, meeting timings are always dependant on the people you need to be present, how long it takes to prepare the room, and whoever has the busiest schedules (As their calendar will be the most dificult to work around). You just need to pick a suitable time and don't care about if it's on or off a nice round number.

Answer (score 0):

It's something that you can try, but I'm not sure it'll succeed in a business setting.

As you said, people are typically used to working to the half hour increments and offsetting that by 15 minutes can lead to some confusion and conflict with other people's schedules.

You're always going to lose some time to small-talk/set-up etc/lateness.  Offsetting the times by 15 minutes isn't going to do anything to prevent this.

You could just assume that you're going to lose 15-20 minutes at the start of the meeting and extend the duration by that time, and people would accept this more readily.  You can offset the longer duration by stating "Hopefully the meeting won't last this long".

If the meeting then gets wrapped up early you can say

> Great, lets end this meeting and I'll let you have that 30 minutes back

And see who cringes.